# Java for loop (sum of numbers + total)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sum

I'm bit lost here. I have a `for` loop which increases a value, something like this:

```
int nu01 = 10000;
int level = 0;
int increase = 35000;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    nu01 = nu01 + increase;
    level++;
    System.out.println(nu01);

    if (level > 50) {
        increase = 45000;
    }
```

This works fine, but I need sum of all numbers from loop as total:

```
loop: 10,20,30,40,50,70,90,120....
total:10,30,60,100,150,220,310,430...
```

I tried:

```
int total;
total=nu01 + nu01; //or  nu01 + nu01 + increase;
```

But I get strange sums. So I need loop which increase numbers and sum of all those numbers. I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want to do is something along the lines of

```
int total = 0;
...
//beginning of your for loop
total = total + nu01; // alternatively you could do total += nu01;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding you here but I believe you want something like this

```
public class forLoops{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Initialisation
        int level = 0;
        int increase = 35000;
        int total = 10000;

        //For Loop
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

            total += increase; //Same as total = total + increase;
            level++;
            System.out.println(total);

        if(level >= 50){

            increase = 45000;

        }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a total variable then store the tota
int total =0;

total += nu01;